# VBA - Error 91 on the last occurence of repeated code

Tags: vba

I'm building a subroutine with a 3 lines bloc repeated 3 times with different inputs, and it works perfectly for most of it but gives an Error 91 on the last line... Which is a twin of the others.

Here is the code :

```
Dim calliper_d, calliper_V, T_log_ini_d, T_log_ini_T, T_log_fin_d, T_log_fin_T As Range
Dim caliper_end_index, T_log_ini_end_index, T_log_fin_end_index As Double 

'Gets the index of the last non empty cell in the corresponding column
caliper_end_index = Application.WorksheetFunction.Match(Worksheets("Main").Range("O4").End(xlDown).Value, Worksheets("Main").Range("O4").EntireColumn.Value, 1)
'Using this index, get the whole first column and the second column up to that point*
calliper_d = Worksheets("Main").Range("O4:O" & caliper_end_index)
calliper_V = Worksheets("Main").Range("Q4:Q" & caliper_end_index)

'same with an other data table
T_log_ini_end_index = Application.WorksheetFunction.Match(Worksheets("Main").Range("K4").End(xlDown).Value, Worksheets("Main").Range("K4").EntireColumn.Value, 1)
T_log_ini_d = Worksheets("Main").Range("K4:K" & T_log_ini_end_index)
T_log_ini_T = Worksheets("Main").Range("L4:L" & T_log_ini_end_index)

'same with an other data table
T_log_fin_end_index = Application.WorksheetFunction.Match(Worksheets("Main").Range("AE4").End(xlDown).Value, Worksheets("Main").Range("AE4").EntireColumn.Value, 1)
T_log_fin_d = Worksheets("Main").Range("AE4:AE" & T_log_fin_end_index)
T_log_fin_T = Worksheets("Main").Range("AF4:AF" & T_log_fin_end_index) 'this is where I get an error
```

*The columns I use for testing are the same size
Digging into the local variables tab, I noticed that for some reason T_log_fin_end_index is registered as a Double while the other two are Variant/Double... which doesn't excuse the fact that it works for T_log_fin_d and not for T_log_fin_T.

I have also checked the test data, there's no problem (no empty cell, no "." instead of ","....). Just a lot of rows of real positive numbers.

Thanks in advance for any help!

Comment: try using Worksheets("Main").Range("K400000").End(xlup).Value

Comment: also `Dim calliper_d, calliper_V, T_log_ini_d, T_log_ini_T, T_log_fin_d, T_log_fin_T As Range` doesn't do as define all as range, just the last one.  `T_log_fin_end_index` , I think would be better served as a long

Comment: I think you are trying to put an array in a non-array, is this the 1st where the index is >4?

Comment: `T_log_fin_T` is a `Range` object reference. Object references must be assigned using the `Set` keyword. Also only 2 of your declared variables have an explicit type, the rest are all implicit `Variant`.

Comment: Ah yes, thank you ! That fixed it. I get more errors down the line, of course, but unrelated to this - so case closed.